# Kubernetes Custom Time-Based Scaler

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minikube

I'm looking to find a way to write a scaler for my application which is running on Minikube to scale it up and down based on Time Stamps. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

That would be an [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) (see its [Walkthrough here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/)), which would  automatically scales the number of pods in a replication controller, deployment or replica set based on observed CPU utilization (or, with **[custom metrics support](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/instrumentation/custom-metrics-api.md)**, on some other application-provided metrics)

In your case, the custom metric would be the time.

You can then follow "[Kubernetes: Horizontal Pod Autoscaler using Minikube](https://itsmetommy.com/2018/07/01/kubernetes-horizontal-pod-autoscaler-using-minikube/)" from [Tommy Elmesewdy](https://twitter.com/r1tommy) as a practical example to implement one such autoscaler on Minikube.

In your case, you should ensure custom metrics are enabled:

```
minikube start --extra-config kubelet.EnableCustomMetrics=true
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The mentioned link is for cpu utilization scaler. Do you have any idea that they have the "time" custom metric or I must write a scaler from scratch?

Comment: @ahmokhtari I suspect you would have to write one: I mention the link "custom metric" in my answer precisely to point out you can have a custom metric, but it might not be already written in your case.